# How to schedule daily dashboard refresh + email in DEVELOPER edition?

Tags: dashboard

How to schedule daily dashboard refresh + email in DEVELOPER edition? I can't find the `Schedule Refresh` button as mentioned [here](http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/dashboards_schedule_refresh.htm). Is this possible in developer edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: It is not available in DEV edition.

As per the docs you pointed the dashboard refresh is available only for Enterprise and Unlimited Editions

In Enterprise Edition and Unlimited Edition, you can schedule dashboards to refresh daily, weekly, or monthly.
Available in: Enterprise and Unlimited Editions

**Improving the answer with screenshots from developer and Unlimited Edition**

Developer Edition

[image]

Unlimited Edition

[image]

Comment: +1 .This feature is only available for Enterprise and Unlimited Edition